# How to create straight lines and tangent fillets in Blender?

Tags: edit-mode

How to create the sketch shown including the fillet (red line). I couldnt find a polyline function as was previously the case for version prior to 3.1.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/curves/editing/introduction.html#set-spline-type

I would like to have this as a cross section so that I can extrude etc Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Object Mode* add a plane with menu *Add* or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Mesh > Plane*

[image]

Then go to *Modifier Properties* and add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier or do the shortcut by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier with three (3) levels. Then click the small down arrow > *Apply*.

[image]

Then press <kbd>tab</kbd> to go into *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>3</kbd> to switch to *Face Select* mode. Then select the faces as shown below and press <kbd>X</kbd> *> Faces* to delete the selected faces.

[image]

Press <kbd>1</kbd> to switch to *Vertex Select* mode and select the vertices encircled in red as shown below then press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Vertices* to delete those vertices. Then press <kbd>tab</kbd> again to go back into *Object Mode* to inspect the shape.

[image]

Press <kbd>tab</kbd> to go into *Edit Mode* again and select two (2) vertices encircled in red as shown below then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *> Cursor to Selected*. This will put the *3D Cursor* right between those vertices. Then add a circle with menu *Add* or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Mesh > Circle*. Set the circle's radius to `0.25m`

[image]

Then select the vertices EXACTLY as shown below and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Vertices* to delete these vertices. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select ALL vertices and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge By Distance*. Notice that 2 vertices have been merged. Those are the 2 vertices from the circle and 2 vertices from the other shape. Now they are fused together. Press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill in a face if you want. Then press <kbd>tab</kbd> to go back into *Object Mode*.

[image]

Comment: I think the asker wants to do this from a curve object, it works for converting meshes to curves, but there are too many steps.

Comment: @XY oh did i just waste my time hahaha.. thanks for the info.

Comment: This is a perfect approach for the cross sections I want to make!!! Thanks a lot for the short cuts too!

Comment: @user9106985 awesome! glad it works out for you, steps are a bit long, maybe could have been shorter but this is a good practice session :)